# Unicode (Malayalam) printing in C# with dot matrix printer

Tags: c#, unicode, printing

When I attempt to print unicode (Malayalam - A south Indian language) with the [RawprinterHelper class](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/f2721e4f-77f6-4d22-9e47-cae0af4d20a8), I am getting junk characters printed. I am using a Dot matrix printer for printing.

Is there any better way for printing South Indian languages using C# ? I need a format like below with dot matrix printer (Epson)

> +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   Date :- 
>   Company Name
>   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   
> Unicode string1 (Malayalam)......Unicode string2 (Malayalam)....Unicode string(n )(Malayalam)
>   etc...........

Comment: Check that link again, at the bottom solution is there

Comment: after that fix also it remains junk printed!!